# Code response code 400 when sending POST params and headers using Volley

Tags: android, http-post, http-status-code-404, android-volley

**I have tried every single method available on stackoverflow but result remains the same.**

> I want to send params and also api key in the Authorization field of header using volley.

Here is the code snippet.

```
 holder.comment_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           String POSTCOMMENT_URL = Utility.getIPADDRESS()+"comments";
           volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
           requestQueue = volleySingleton.getRequestQueue();
           JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, POSTCOMMENT_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.e("Response:  " , response.toString());
                   Toast.makeText(myApplication.getApplicationContext(),response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   Toast.makeText(myApplication.getApplicationContext(),"Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           }){
               @Override
               public String getBodyContentType() {
                   return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
               }
               @Override
               public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                   Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
                   params.put("Authorization", getApiKey() );
                   return params;
               }

               @Override
               protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                   Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
                   params.put("pid", "39");
                   params.put("comment", "mobile testing");
                   return params;
               }

           };
           requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
       }
   });
```

I'm getting this error:

> [5333] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://www.XXXXXXXXXXX.com/comments

**I have already tested the endpoint using Advanced Rest client, it works and returns the JsonObject with previously added comment.**

Here are the results:

```
{
"error": false
"message": "comment added successfully added!"
"comment_id": "12"
"user_id": "12"
"pid": "39"
"comment": "testing for stackoverflow"
"date of comment": "2016-07-30 13:49:08"
}
```

Comment: What does 400 mean?

Comment: The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. In short _Bad network request_.

Comment: `String POSTCOMMENT_URL = Utility.getIPADDRESS()+"comments";`. That should be `String POSTCOMMENT_URL = Utility.getIPADDRESS()+"/comments";`? If not then the function name is confusing.

Comment: The point is if it ends with a `/` ? Please react.

Comment: Inside getIPADDRESS() it's handled with `/`.

Comment: What ever is inside we dont care. We want to know what is returned by getIPADDRES(). If it ends with a `/`. If it returns something like `http://<ipdress>/` then you could better name it `getUrl()`.

Comment: Yes it ends with `/` .

Comment: And does it start with `http://` ? Is it an url? We cannot see what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, it does contain proper url.

Comment: By the time I was making the class I was using localhost, but not now, Sorry I didn't change the name of the function. But that isn't related to the problem.

Comment: Try adding content type to the header?

Comment: @Slartibartfast just got it running, check out answer below, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a long research and stupid rather valuable changes, it finally worked for me.

Here is the working code:

```
holder.comment_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(final View view) {

           final String api_key = getApiKey();
           String POSTCOMMENT_URL = Utility.getIPADDRESS()+"comments";
           volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
           requestQueue = volleySingleton.getRequestQueue();
           StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, POSTCOMMENT_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(myApplication.getApplicationContext(),response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   Toast.makeText(myApplication.getApplicationContext(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           }) {

               @Override
               public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                   Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
                   params.put("Authorization", api_key);
                   return params;
               }

              @Override
               protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                   Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
                   params.put("pid", "40");
                   params.put("comment", "testing");
                   return params;
               }

           };
           requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
       }
   });
```

> Note: It worked for me, I'm not sure about others.

Changes are: **Change JsonObjectRequest to StringRequest** and **removing any Content-Type doesn't make any difference**, so I removed it.

> Also, make sure all the params have some values i.e test it by logging.